# Public object not being recognized by internal action

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am creating a script in QTP, it has a few internal actions (ActionA, ActionB...) and I have an associated function library commonFunctions.vbs

In my commonFunctions I have the code below:

```
Public PageA, PageB
Set PageA = Browser("A").Page("A")
Set PageB = Browser("A").Page("B")
```

And in ActionB (which is called by ActionA), I am making use of these Object variables:

```
If PageB.Link("someLink").Exist Then
    PageB.Link("someLink").Click
End If
```

ActionA and ActionB both have the object repository used by the variables.

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'PageB.Link'
Line (4): "If PageB.Link("someLink").Exist Then".
```

What am I missing? How come the variables are not defined in ActionB?

I feel like this is something simple but I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't appear to be the scope, but rather that sometimes QTP doesn't recognize the page object.

Try giving the condition explicitly like:

```
If Browser("A").Page("B").Link.Exists Then
'~~~~~~~code
```

Also, this article may help a little:

http://www.joecolantonio.com/2010/08/12/quicktest-object-recognition/

Comment: Explicitly it works fine, I was just trying to make it easier to code and look cleaner

Answer (score 0):

To Pass data from Action 1 to Action 2, you would required input/output parameters. It doesn't depends on type of variable (Public,...).

```
In Action 1 -
Set PageB = Browser("A").Page("B")
LocalParameter(param) = PageB 

In Action 2 -
Set PageB =LocalParameter(param)
PageB.Link("someLink").Click
```

Here "LocalParameter" is QTP's Utility Object, which can be used to pass value from one Action to another.